# table with name "order" : invalid table name

Tags: oracle

I understand why. I know, this name is really not valid. But this table exists in my DB. I can't rename it. I have no permission. 
But, may be, there is a some choice for me? How can I execute something like

> select COUNT(*) from "order";

? Thanks.

**Obs: Thanks for all, problem resolved.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle stores table names in upper case, so you need:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM "ORDER"
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in Oracle

```
create table "order" (c1 number);
```

Table created.

```
select COUNT(*) from "order"
```

COUNT(*)
0

Comment: If you put table name in quotes, the tablename is case sensitive. You created "order" and select from "order" which works fine, but if the table name is "ORDER" or even "Order" "select * from "order"" wont work.